# Range of Random Variable

Tags: random-variable, terminology

I understand that the Random variable is a function such as, $RV:\sigma-field(\Bbb C) \rightarrow range \;of \;random\;variable \in\Bbb R$ where $\Bbb C$ denotes sample space.

Is there any particular name for the range of random variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of possible values that random variable can take is called its [support](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_%28mathematics%29). I don't think that there is any name for range. Support is a broader and more precise term. For example, say that random variable can take only non-negative, integer values -- range wouldn't tell us that we are interested only in integers. [Cantor distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_distribution) is an example of distribution with complicated support.